# Canvas onload event isn't firing

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I can't get the `onload` event to work for a `Canvas` element.  Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="modelZone" onload="initializeCanvas();" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here's the Javascript in `main.js`:

```
function initializeCanvas(){
    alert("hello");
}
```

I know that the HTML is finding `main.js`, because if I change `onload` to `onclick` it works correctly: clicking in the region of the Canvas triggers an alert.  So why can't I do this with `onload`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Only the body element (and perhaps iframe) can fire a onload event. Simply put `<script> initializeCanvas(); </script>` after the `<canvas>` tag.

Comment: This is the right answer, I just want to add that `onload` can be attached to `<body>`, `<frame>`, `<frameset>`, `<iframe>`, `<img>`, `<input type="image">`, `<link>`, `<script>` and `<style>`

Comment: Yes, it would fire after the canvas element has been created, but the canvas content has not yet been loaded. So if you want to do something with the canvas, it might not yet be possible.

Comment: Brilliant!  
12 hours looking for some `magic plugin`... and the natural behavior of a script - read it line by line - does the trick! Obviously...