# Replace the canvas with text

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have the canvas and I want to fill the text on canvas load.My canvas is loaded on dynamically
I have called the onload function for the canvas.But Its not executed

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "30px Arial";
ctx.fillText("Hello World",10,50);
function myFunction(){
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "30px Arial";
 ctx.fillText('HTML5 Canvas Tutorial', 10, 50); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas class="canvas" id="canvas" width="200" height="100"
style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;" onload="myFunction();"></canvas>
```

Comment: `onload` is not available on `canvas`.

Comment: canvas element doesn't support **onload** event, consider using `document.body.onload`.

Comment: Check your [] ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22670482/canvas-onload-event-isnt-firing)

Answer (score 1):

Issue was that the `onload` attribute should be used on the `body` tag. Move it there and you should be fine. Also, modify your `myFunction` function like so to clear the canvas first.

Fixed code:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "30px Arial";
ctx.fillText("Hello World",10,50);
function myFunction(){
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 ctx.fillText('HTML5 Canvas Tutorial', 10, 50); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body onload="myFunction();">
<canvas class="canvas" id="canvas" width="200" height="100"
style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
</body>
```